# Allow one method call at a time per user

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a WebAPI endpoint that calls a service method which I want to exit immediately if the previous service method call has not completed *for the same user.* It seems like a Semaphore might be the way to go, but I'm not sure how to make it per user. I will have a (int)UserKey for the user.

In other words, how can I supply a context to a Semaphore? In this case, the context would be the UserKey.

Comment: perhaps you can explain what it is you're trying to accomplish as well as show some code to depict what you are doing / trying to accomplish.

Comment: We definitely need to see your code and to know (much) more about what you are trying to do.  Conceptually, you will need to have some kind of data-structure ... a "tote-board," if you will ... where the process that's admitting new requests-for-service can determine reliably if a request is already running for this particular UserKey.  If so, it would reject the new request with an appropriate error message and/or code.

Comment: You need to see code to tell me how to supply context to a Semaphore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about storing in a database some sort of flag that indicates that you have pending requests from a certain user?

Comment: ... a database is a *very* nice idea, particularly if you use **transactions** to reliably isolate the various queries that are reading and/or updating this table.